# flextable: `fontsize(size = 4, part = "all")` does not apply to the footnote

Tags: r, fonts, flextable

I had expected that the `fontsize(size = 4, part = "all")` would apply `size = 4` on all parts of the table. It doesn't.

```
head(iris) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  fontsize(size = 4, part = "all") %>%
  footnote( i = 1, j = 1:2,
               value = as_paragraph(
                c("This is footnote one",
                   "This is footnote two")
               ),
               ref_symbols = c("a", "b"),
               part = "header") %>%
  footnote(i = 1, j = 3:4,
               value = as_paragraph(
                 c("This is footnote three",
                   "This is footnote four")
               ),
               ref_symbols = c("c","d"),
               part = "header")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order matters - move `fontsize()` to after the creation of the footnotes:

```
head(iris) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  footnote( i = 1, j = 1:2,
            value = as_paragraph(
              c("This is footnote one",
                "This is footnote two")
            ),
            ref_symbols = c("a", "b"),
            part = "header") %>%
  footnote(i = 1, j = 3:4,
           value = as_paragraph(
             c("This is footnote three",
               "This is footnote four")
           ),
           ref_symbols = c("c","d"),
           part = "header") %>%
  fontsize(size = 4, part = "all")
```

[image]